# Idiomatic Scala solution to imperative code

Tags: algorithm, scala, collections, idioms

What are some ideas for expressing this function in 'idiomatic' Scala. Or more precisely, is there a way to remove the local vars without sacrificing readability?

```
def solve(threshold: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = {
  var sum = 0
  var curr = 0
  while(sum < threshold) {
   sum += f(curr)
   curr += 1
  }
  curr
}
```

The only thing I could come up with was this, but it's longer and less readable in my opinion.

```
def solve2(threshold: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = {
  val resultIterator = Iterator.iterate (0, 0) { case (curr, sum) =>
    (curr + 1, sum + f(curr))
  }
  (resultIterator find (_._2 >= threshold)).get._1
}
```

Comment: It was hard to decide which one to make _correct_ since all were good so I picked the one that seemed most intuitive to me

Comment: @Dan Burton's solution gave me the most new tricks for the toolbox though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most direct approach is to turn the while loop into a nested tail-recursive function.

```
def solve(threshold: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = {
    def solveLoop(sum: Int, curr: Int): Int = if (sum < threshold) {
        solveLoop(sum + f(curr), curr + 1)
    } else {
        curr
    }
    solveLoop(0,0)
}
```

This is the standard "functional" way of looping.

Comment: Upon reflection, this is simply the un-abstracted version of my "until" solution. :)

Answer (score 13):

```
def solve(threshold: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = {
  Iterator.from(0).map(f).scanLeft(0)(_ + _).indexWhere(threshold <=)
}
```

In my opinion, the loop version is much clearer.

Answer (score 7):

You could

```
def solve(threshold: Int, i: Int = 0)(f: Int => Int) = {
  if (threshold <= 0) i else solve(threshold - f(i), i+1)(f)
}
```

but I'm not sure that's actually clearer.  Note that it's actually more characters than a compact version of the while loop:

```
def solve(threshold: Int)(f: Int => Int) = {
  var s,i = 0; while (s < threshold) { s += f(i); i += 1 }; i
}
```

Loops with mutable variables aren't always bad, "idiomatic" or no.  Just keep the mutable state safely contained within the function, and all anyone else sees is a stateless function to call.

Incidentally, although `sum` is a sensible variable name, `curr` is questionable.  What's wrong with `i`?  It's widely used as an index variable, and anyway, having a variable at all is a nuisance; the point is you take something and increment it, whatever it is, by one step each time, and then return it.  It is this flow of logic, not the name, which tells you (and others) what it is for.

Comment: I found `curr` distracting too.

Comment: You're right about the variable naming. I can only say in the original context the name made a bit more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it in Haskell:

```
solve threshold f = snd $ until test step (0, 0)
  where test (sum, i) = sum >= threshold
        step (sum, i) = (sum + f i, succ i)
```

This clearly marks the `test`, the `step`, and the initial values, just like the imperative version. I am not sure if scala has `until` in the libs somewhere, but it is trivial to define:

```
def until[A](test: A => Boolean)(f: A => A)(v: A): A = {
  if (test(v)) {
    v
  } else {
    until(test)(f)(f(v))
  }
}

def solve(threshold: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = {
  def test = (sum: Int, i: Int) => sum >= threshold
  def step = (sum: Int, i: Int) => (sum + f(i), i + 1)
  until(test.tupled)(step.tupled)((0, 0))._2
}
```

Comment: +1, That looks like a very handy function. You should add an equivalent Scala to your answer IMO.

Comment: @missingfaktor done :) I wrote the original last night on my phone and was too lazy to test it out in Scala. Not sure if my liberal use of currying here is compatible with Scala's tail call optimization, but what can I say, I like Haskell's currying.

Answer (score 1):

I always wonder when people talk about 'idiomatic' scala. Because in my opinion everyone has his own perception of idiomatic. If you are looking for a functional solution I would like to suggest you to take a look at the 'essence of the iterator pattern' . There is actually a very good blogpost in scala about this check it out here : http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html

Comment: Can you please show with some code how is `traverse` relevant here?

Comment: Well if you look at : threshold, sum and cur . What does he do with those values? He uses those to generate a finite 'stream' of values which he than applies his function to. Convinced? :)

Comment: Well if you look at : threshold, sum and cur . What does he do with those values? He uses those to generate a finite 'stream' of values which he than applies his function to. Convinced? Actually, I like the scanLeft implementation better. Idiomatic is very subjective, some people mean terse or what ever. Generating a sequence and applying a function while threading state through. It depends how you like to express that.

Comment: Yes, it's relevant. Thanks. +1. The solution doesn't meet my (subjective) definition of clarity/readability though.